# duplicated dynamic loading : segmention fault

Tags: segmentation-fault, dlopen, loadlibrary

I wrote a library which use `tesseract.dll` and `leptonica.dll` with dynamic loading (`LoadLibrary` on Windows and `dlopen` on Linux). Tesseract also use leptonica internally, but it's implict loading not dynamic loading.

My library works well in windows but when ported it to Ubuntu, it segfaults when tesseract lib calls a leptonica function. It may be caused by duplicate symbol.

If I change leptonica loading to implicit loading (by adding `-llept` to `LDFLAGS`), segmention fault when tesseract calls the first leptonica function (`convertOnBigEnd16`) disappears.

How can I load a libray with `dlopen`, which is already loaded with implict loading?

I have tried the followings.

```
dlopen("liblept.so", RTLD_LAZY|RTLD_NOLOAD|RTLD_GLOBAL); //(dlopen manual says ' a library that was previously loaded with RTLD_LOCAL can be reopened with RTLD_NOLOAD | RTLD_GLOBAL')
dlopen("liblept.so", RTLD_LAZY|RTLD_LOCAL);
```

but all trials are segmentation fault (all `dlopen` and `dlsym` return success and function pointers are normal but cause segfault)

[bliefly other trials]

implicit loading of `libtesseract.so` + implicit loading of `liblept.so` in lib : working good

`dlopen` of `libtesseract.so` + `dlopen` of `liblept.so` in main : working good

`dlopen` of `libtesseract.so` + `dlopen` of `liblept.so` in lib : seg fault

Why only the last case causes segfault?

At fault time, the leptonica function pointer is not null and debugger says

```
No source available for "convertOnBigEnd16() at 0x7ffff7dd4290
```

and disassembled code does not match `objdump`'s output.

How can I load a libray with `dlopen` in lib after it's already been loaded implictly?

Comment: Are you sure you `dlopen` the same versions of libraries that are loaded implicitly?

Comment: I'm confirmed the same version/file with ldd. thanks a lot